# I'm having problems when adding the JPA dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
<!-- jpa -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>        
</dependency>
```

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.isCandidateClass(SpringTransactionAnnotationParser.java:44)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.isCandidateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
```

The method's class, org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/gustavo.felix/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/gustavo.felix/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils

Comment: I think we need a whole lot more data to go on than this, specifically your POM file(s). It sounds like the dependency management is messed up.

Comment: provide your entire pom file. I guess there is a problem with your `starter-parent` dependency or a problem with your dependency management